# Should I update a question's title to help people with the same problem find it?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926177/debugging-crash-in-unity-build) last night. The title reflects the problem I was having at the time - i.e. I was struggling to find the cause of a crash in the build.

Having spent a long time in a chat with an extremely helpful user today, we found the problem - Calling a Unity method (as described in the documentation) before setting a property causes the build to crash, with no useful logs to help find the problem. We located that problem related to that type of object fairly quickly, but spent a long time testing all of the input data and so on before I tried removing the call pretty much entirely on a whim.

I've added an answer describing the problem, but it strikes me it is unlikely to be found with the current title.

- Should I update the title to reflect the solution relates to dynamic meshes?
- If so, I assume I shouldn't use brackets on the end of the current title or anything - should I go with *Unity Build crash caused by dynamic mesh* or similar?

In short; should I ever change the title of a question *after finding the answer* to help link it to the cause?

---

Edit:

I went with: *Unity full build crashes when using dynamic meshes*.

All of my searches would have still located it, and seeing "dynamic meshes" might have got me thinking along those lines sooner.

Comment: Does this having anything to do with *building* the program?  It sounds like a plain AVE when *running* the program.

Comment: @HansPassant I think that comment belongs on the source question, not on this meta question.

Comment: Quite right though, nothing to do with the C# build process, but "running the full Unity build" rather than running it from within the editor. Not sure if that should be clarified as "the Unity build" or what really..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

You should definitely always be open to changing your question's title if you find a good reason, **but** you should be considerate of the implications.

If you change the title to something more accurate, specific, and/or detailed, that might make more sense once you are aware of those details... but you weren't when you asked the question. That means others with the same problem as you might not know to ask it the way you now know how to ask it; they might think to ask it in a more broad or less accurate way.

In those cases, it's actually *more* helpful to leave it as it is (or find some compromise between the two ends) so that users with a similar problem (who are likely to search with a similar query) can find it. Then they can simply learn from your question (or better yet, an answer) that there's a better way to think about it.

In this case I would recommend changing the title, because "Debugging a crash in Unity" is typically too broad a question to ask.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm thinking - to start with I had basically nothing to work with - the crash logs contained only "`Crash!`".. then I worked out it was to do with dynamic meshes, and it still took effort from there to find the ACTUAL cause.

Comment: @Octopoid Ideally such research would take place before asking the question :-D But I understand it can be difficult sometimes without the help of others.

Comment: Yep - the question was originally "please tell me there's some way of finding the source of this crash without commenting out my entire codebase class by class" - and the answer was no.. ;)